# How do I validate and benchmark a new protein or polymer model?

Tags: proteins, polymers

Suppose I designed a novel coarse-grained model of polymer chains.

How can I test the validity of my novel model?

Is there any applied framework available?

Comment: Mostly, you will need to validate your model against long range structural properties like radius of gyration and end to end distance.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha elaborate please.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha why don't you elaborate and post an answer? Comments are for clarifying the question.

Comment: Thanks @NikeDattani I will do that now.